# How remove css class in code behind .net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, .net

My div contains 4 css class I whant to delete one from them
for adding I do this:

```
MyDivId.Attributes["class"] += " addedClass";
```

in newest framework they can be done like this:

```
MyDivId.CssClass.Replace("addedClass", "");
```

but in .net 2.0 not found `CssClass`

some proposals?
thx in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the same. CssClass just return string, so you can do like this

```
MyDivId.Attributes["class"] = MyDivId.Attributes["class"].Replace("addedClass", "");
```

**UPDATE1**

Or just more easy to use way to create extension class that will do the same:

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
    public static void RemoveCssClass(this HtmlControl control, string cssClassName)
    {
        var val = control.Attributes["class"];
        val = val.Replace(cssClassName, string.Empty);
        control.Attributes["class"] = val;
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
MyDivId.RemoveCssClass("addedClass");
```